# pod spec lint or pod lib lint fails while updating cocoapods library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4.2

I'm trying to update my [GLNotification](https://github.com/gokulgovind/GLNotificationBar) cocopods version.

I had switched over from **Xcode 9.4 -> Xcode 10**. I had converted my code to latest swift version, after that i'm unable to update my pods.

But there is no warning or error in my code. It works fine. Download my code [here](https://github.com/gokulgovind/GLNotificationBar) .

**My Pods Spec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'GLNotificationBar'
s.version          = '2.3.6'
s.summary          = 'GLNotificationBar lets user to handle push  notification when app is active.'

s.description      = <<-DESC
GLNotificationBar is a open source library that lets developers to display push notification or any alert message to end user as banner. iOS below 10 does't displays notification when app is active. This library is inspired by Apple's ios10 notification bar.
DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/gokulgovind/GLNotificationBar'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'gokul' => 'gokulece26@gmail.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/gokulgovind/GLNotificationBar.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
s.source_files = 'GLNotificationBar/Classes/**/*'
s.resource_bundles = {
'GLNotificationBar' => ['GLNotificationBar/Classes/*.xib','GLNotificationBar/Assets/*.png']
}
s.frameworks = 'UIKit'

end
```

**Error**

```
-> GLNotificationBar (2.3.6)
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:247:59: error: type 'UIWindow' has no member 'Level'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:278:44: error: type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:323:69: error: type 'UIWindow' has no member 'Level'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:419:115: error: type 'UIResponder' has no member 'keyboardWillShowNotification'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:420:114: error: type 'UIResponder' has no member 'keyboardWillHideNotification'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:486:44: error: type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:487:44: error: type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:489:44: error: type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:527:64: error: type 'UIControl' has no member 'State'
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  UIKit.UIControl:16:14: note: did you mean 'state'?
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:528:90: error: type 'UIControl' has no member 'Event'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:744:55: error: type 'UIWindow' has no member 'Level'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:813:80: error: type 'UIView' has no member 'AnimationOptions'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:916:33: error: type 'UITextField' has no member 'BorderStyle'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:920:38: error: type 'UIControl' has no member 'State'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:922:67: error: type 'UIControl' has no member 'State'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:990:47: error: type 'UIWindow' has no member 'Level'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:1005:43: error: type 'UIResponder' has no member 'keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:1018:43: error: type 'UIResponder' has no member 'keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:1123:27: error: type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  GLNotificationBar/GLNotificationBar/Classes/GLNotificationBar.swift:1132:27: error: type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'
```

**Fix I Tried**

- Added `s.swift_version = '4.1'` in my `GLNotificationBar.podspec`
- Changed `Swift Language Version` to 4.2 in Build Settings
- Updated iOS deployment target from iOS 8 to iOS 10

**Terminal Command I Tried**

```
 pod spec lint GLNotificationBar.podspec
 pod spec lint
 pod spec lint --allow-warnings
```

Comment: FYI the latest tag is failing on their own repo. https://travis-ci.org/gokulgovind/GLNotificationBar.  NVM just realized it's *your* own repo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the Swift language version in your pod spec? 
It might be a compilation issue for mismatched language versions. 
[image: I see this in your pod spec file.]

[This](https://github.com/gokulgovind/GLNotificationBar/commit/8abd15f1927e078d9691a756fd38f971205aa070) is your latest commit and it's still set to an earlier version of Swift than the project settings.

Comment: I had added s.swift_version while trying to fix this issue. Even after removing that i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you moved to X-Code 10, it supports swift 4 and 4.2 as of now, so you need to have same in build settings as well as in Pods Spec.

If you are not using swift 3,4 and 4.2 then need to go to File->Workspace Setting

and select build system to Legacy Build System.

You need to commit everything and push to git.

Update tag to new version and push to tag.

Then try to push to Cocoapods pod trunk push --allow-warnings.

Let me know if you get any issues after you try this.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your suggestion. but still i'm getting the same error